# 32 GB RAM showing up as 1.3 GB all of a sudden in Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: ram

So my laptop screen went blank at a point and I had to manually restart. The laptop has a 32 GB single DIMM installed. But since the restart, the RAM has been showing up as 1.3 GB. `memtest86` detected 32 GB and couldn't find any errors in the RAM.

How I realized this is that the laptop had become incredibly slow, with even mouse movements being choppy and laggy, and I found out about the RAM while trying to diagnose the issue. I've restarted several times while trying to diagnose the issue and *once* it did switch back to 32 GB, but I don't know what I did to make it happen. I am at my wits end and before I purchase a new RAM DIMM, I wanted to see if I can get some pointers to try here. Here's some supplemental information.

```
> sudo dmidecode | grep Size
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: No Module Installed
    Range Size: 32 GB
    Installed Size: 128 kB
    Maximum Size: 128 kB
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Installed Size: 3072 kB
    Maximum Size: 3072 kB
    Range Size: 32 GB

> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          1.3Gi       558Mi       193Mi       264Mi       547Mi       270Mi
Swap:         7.9Gi       1.4Gi       6.5Gi

> cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        1330824 kB
MemFree:           88652 kB
MemAvailable:     159892 kB
Buffers:           29268 kB
Cached:           520304 kB
SwapCached:       107812 kB
Active:           497052 kB
Inactive:         411028 kB
Active(anon):     388576 kB
Inactive(anon):   311352 kB
Active(file):     108476 kB
Inactive(file):    99676 kB
Unevictable:       13216 kB
Mlocked:              64 kB
SwapTotal:       8265212 kB
SwapFree:        6719740 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        365508 kB
Mapped:           158148 kB
Shmem:            341436 kB
KReclaimable:      73840 kB
Slab:             213492 kB
SReclaimable:      73840 kB
SUnreclaim:       139652 kB
KernelStack:       13984 kB
PageTables:        25304 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     8930624 kB
Committed_AS:    7254880 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       37824 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             3456 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      300972 kB
DirectMap2M:     3774464 kB
DirectMap1G:    29360128 kB
```

I've got the `memtest86` log. But it's too big to add and I am not sure if it has some sort of identifying information which shouldn't be out on the internet. So if there is anything specific I could grep for in the log, please let me know and I can add that here.

Comment: Definitely strange.  Maybe try doing a hard power cycle of your laptop.  On most laptops it is performed by powering off the laptop and holding in the power button for 15-30 seconds then powering it back on.  Some laptops you might have to pull the power and the battery then press the power button a few times, then hook the power and battery back in and power on.

Comment: Since once it did switch back to 32GB there’s no need to buy a new DIMM.  Try booting from a thumb drive to see what it says.

Comment: I might have power cycled it without knowing during my multiple attempts to fix it, as I haven't had this problem for a few days now.